# Can't load custom DLL

Tags: c++, powershell, dll

I created a simple DLL that open cmd.exe.

I did it with these options:
[image]
[image]

In the default `dlllmain.cpp` I added a code that creates a new `cmd.exe`:

```
// dllmain.cpp : Defines the entry point for the DLL application.
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    {
        STARTUPINFO info = { sizeof(info) };
        PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo;
        BOOL h = CreateProcessW(L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe", L"", NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &info, &processInfo);
    }
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

These three lines below the `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH` worked for me when I tested it with a console application.

I am expecting that every process that will load this DLL will open `cmd.exe`.

I tried to load the DLL with PowerShell:

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
    using System;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    public static class Kernel32
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError=true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
            public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(
                [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string lpFileName); 
} 


"@

    $LibHandle = [Kernel32]::LoadLibrary("C:\tmp\myDll.dll")
```

But nothing happens, the value of the `$LibHandle` was `0`.

What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Don't put code in DllMain see Warning and also Remarks in: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @RichardCritten I tried also to create a `DllLoader.h` and put the function's ginature there and moved all the code (3 lines) to `DllLoader.cpp` in a function named `OpenCmd()`. Below `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH` I put `OpenCmd()`. I tried to load it with PowerShell, still nothing.

Comment: Unclear: did you call OpenCmd() directly from PowerShell?  Please post the modified code.

Comment: @RichardCritten No, I didn't call `OpenCmd()` directly. I am not planning to call for exported function in DLL. I want to load this DLL inside some process and when it will be loaded, it will go to the entry point and run the function.

Comment: Untill DllMain returns doing almost anything is Microsoft's equivalent of Undefined Behaviour.  There is no point is reasoning about program behaviour or suggesting fixes as there are no guarantees that any call into the OS will behave correctly.

Comment: @RichardCritten That's exaggerated.

Comment: @manuell The problem is MS gives you a list of functions that definitely won't work and a guidance  not to make any OS calls except into `Kernel32.dll`.  The specific problem is making OS calls that make other OS calls (eg secondary calls to LoadLibrary).  There is no list of safe OS calls. see this list from MS: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn633971(v=vs.85).aspx#general_best_practices  I say it's just too complicated unless you are an MS-OS expert already.  For someone learning point them at the docs and give a general rule is all we can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what was the problem.
My system is 64 bit and the file was compiled in 32 bit.
I needed to specify in Visual Studio that I am compiling it in x64 bit.
[image]

I didn't check it in the beginning because I thought that when I am compiling it on "Any CPU" mode, it compile the file in 64 bit automatically as the OS architecture.

Now it works fine.